# CORS error, but only when I am sending a file from Lumen v8

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, lumen

I have an app that is a VueJS front-end with Lumen v8 back-end.

The API needs to be on a different URL, but my middleware should be handling that anyway.

The purpose of the feature is to set filters and then download a CSV of users. If I change the response as detailed below to send pure text, or JSON-formatted data, the GET call works fine. But if I use `return response()->download()` then it returns this CORS error:

[image: CORS error]

Here is the code in the controller:

```
public function csv(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $response = $this->list($request);

        if ($response) {
            $content = json_decode($response->content(), true);

            $csv = jsonToCsv($content['users']);
            $filename = 'users_' . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d_Hi') . '.css';
            Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, $csv);
            $file_path = storage_path('app/' . $filename);
            return response()->download($file_path, $filename, [
                'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
            ]);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['errors' => $e->getMessage(), 'reason' => request('status_reason')], 409);
    }
}
```

I have this middleware set up in Lumen:

```
class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $http_origin     = request()->getHost();
        $allowed_origins = config('server.cors_allowed_origins');
        $allow_origin    = in_array($http_origin, $allowed_origins) ? $http_origin : null;

        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*', //implode(', ', $allow_origin),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Here is the script calling it in the VueJS:

```
  getCSV (payload) {
    let url = 'admin/user/csv'

    if (payload !== null) {
      url += '?'
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(payload)) {
        if (value !== null) {
          url += key + '=' + value + '&'
        }
      }
    }

    return API.get(url, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }).then(result => {
      return result
    }).catch(e => {
      if (e.status === 401) {
        localStorage.setItem('sun_token', '')
        document.location.href = '/#/auth/sign-in1'
      }
      throw e
    })
  }
```

Like I said at the top, if I change the controller to return text, it goes through. I know I'm missing something, but have no idea what.

Comment: The second error shown is a 500 Internal Server Error, and most likely the cause for the first one (a failing script will probably not send your CORS header as you intended) - so go check the error log and figure out the reason for the 500.

Comment: oh, that would make sense :facepalm: